# How does Perl compare strings under the hood?

Tags: perl

Does Perl just compare the ASCII values of each character of each string until it can place one before the other or does the language compare strings in another way?

Comment: This can get very complicated if you think about locales and collation. http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Equality-Operators "lt", "le", "ge", "gt" and "cmp" use the collation (sort) order specified by the current locale if a legacy use locale (but not use locale ':not_characters' ) is in effect. See perllocale. Do not mix these with Unicode, only with legacy binary encodings. The standard Unicode::Collate and Unicode::Collate::Locale modules offer much more powerful solutions to collation issues.

Comment: @Thilo Can you make that into an answer?

Answer (score 1):

[Perl does take your current locale into account](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllocale.html) and uses the sort order defined by this locale. This does not only take charsets (such as ASCII) into account but also languages. For instance words are sorted differently in French than in German, etc…

Comment: I don't think the questioner is talking about sorting but a simple $foo eq $bar.